# Нужно подгрузить head с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html

В проекте есть html код, который используется как отдельно, так и подгружается к другой страницы. Поэтому в первом случае необходимо добавлять к нему head, а во втором нет. Пробовал реализовать через js, но по какой-то причине стили срабатывают, а кодировка нет

```
<script>
    if (window.location.pathname.toString() == "/avents/src/content/about.html") {
    let head = document.createElement("head");
    console.log(head);
    document.head.innerHTML = `     <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.min.css">`;
}
</script>

<div>пример текста</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: react vue - возьмите , они в аккурат для компонентной вёрстки

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, проблема в том, что JavaScript выполняется после получения ответа от сервера.

То есть, когда сервер обращается к вашей, ещё не скомпилированной странице, он видит, что тега `<head>` ещё нет. И устанавливает кодировку в соответствие с настройкой сервера.

По этой причине стили, а так же title и description встают без проблем, а кодировка игнорируется

Попробуйте задать необходимую вам кодировку в настройках сервера

Comment: кодировка нужная стоит в настройках сервера

Comment: Когда вы открываете страницу, в заголовках сервера лежит "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"?
Если что, просмотреть заголовки открытой страницы, можно в "инструменты разработчика", во вкладке Network (ctr+shift+i или f12)

Comment: Тип контента да, кодировки нет. 
На данный момент добавил meta и link сразу и написал скрипт, который удаляет лишние meta и link если страницу подгружаю в другой файл

Comment: Если в заголовках нет прямого тега кодировки, то значит, что она не задана. А в таком случае (скорее всего) кодировка будет тянуть в cp-1251.